# Is it possible to read the Slog in android monitor?

Tags: android, android-log

In the android source code i see often line like `Slog.v(WindowManagerService.TAG, "First window added to " + this + ", creating SurfaceSession");` How can i see those **Slog** under android monitor ? And what the difference between Slog and Log?

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**

You get logs logged with `Slog` by default, but they are "hidden" between other log messages. In order to get just the ones logged with `Slog` use this command:

```
adb logcat -b system
```

**Long answer**

I looked at source of `Slog.java`:

```
public static int v(String tag, String msg) {
    return Log.println_native(Log.LOG_ID_SYSTEM, Log.VERBOSE, tag, msg);
}
```

Compared to `Log.java`:

```
public static int v(String tag, String msg) {
    return println_native(LOG_ID_MAIN, VERBOSE, tag, msg);
}
```

As you can see, the difference is solely in `LOG_ID` parameter.

Then I looked at `adb logcat -help`:

```
  ...
  -b <buffer>     Request alternate ring buffer, 'main', 'system', 'radio',
                  'events', 'crash' or 'all'. Multiple -b parameters are
                  allowed and results are interleaved. The default is
                  -b main -b system -b crash.
  ...
```

I did not check any further - it looks like a safe bet that `-b` option corresponds to different `LOG_ID` params.

Comment: thanks vasiliy, if i do adb logcat -b system do i will see the log appear in android monitor or just in the windows console ?

Comment: @loki I always use command line. Maybe there is a way to get it in Android Studio, but I don't know how...